# Precise Result for Image to Text Conversion Using Tesseract Framework

Tags: ios, tesseract

I am using `tesseract` library to develop Business Card Reader. But not getting the precise output for many cards.

There is an app in the App Store called `SamCard`, it works 90% correctly.

How can I achieve this result using the `tesseract` library?